# Why does command grouping with curly brackets cause two bash shells to be spawned?

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

Consider the following command

```
$ bash -c "  sleep 10000  | sed 's/ Something//g '"
```

The process tree due to that command looks like this;

```
   \-+= 69771 hbaba -bash
     \-+= 39225 hbaba bash -c   sleep 10000  | sed 's/ Something//g '
       |--- 39226 hbaba sleep 10000
       \--- 39227 hbaba sed s/ Something//g
```

Adding [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) with curly brackets changes the process tree significantly.

```
$ bash -c " { sleep 10000; } | sed 's/ Something//g '"
```

The bash process is spawned twice

```
 \-+= 69771 hbaba -bash
         \-+= 39323 hbaba bash -c  { sleep 10000; } | sed 's/ Something//g '
           |-+- 39324 hbaba bash -c  { sleep 10000; } | sed 's/ Something//g '
           | \--- 39326 hbaba sleep 10000
           \--- 39325 hbaba sed s/ Something//g
```

What is the reason of this duplication ?

---

The documentation [section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) about curly braces mentions this:

> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be
>   executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created.

What I see does not look like current shell context to me. A new subshell should not be created. We are not using parenthesis.

---

I understand that bash spawns each process in a pipe in its own subshell

From the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell

I am not asking why the `sleep` and `sed` are two different processes. I am asking about the two bashes: 39323 and 39324

---

I am using this bash version

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
```

---

**Update**

I have found this related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127334/212862) in Unix&Linux . I think that answers it. There is still some unclarified aspects though. In that question the curly braces were nested. In addition, this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127337/212862) there shows that the extra subshell creation happens with pipes but not with semicolon separated commands.

Indeed this command does not create the extra subshell.

```
bash -c " { sleep 10000; } ; sed 's/ Something//g '"
```

Here is the process tree. I guess the parallel execution of piped commands also plays a role in this extra subshell creation.

```
bash,100648
  └─bash,104674 -c  { sleep 10000; } ; sed 's/ Something//g '
      └─sleep,104675 10000
```

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you, but look about 10 lines up in `man bash` 4th paragraph under `Lists`, "*Commands separated by a `;` are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate in  turn. The return status is the exit status of the last command executed.*". The only thing that stands out is the additional process seems to be necessary to keep track of the sequential execution of commands due to the `';'` within the braces and not the braces themselves. I need to look further, but thought I would pass that along.

Comment: Same on version 4.4.12

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Do you mean the `;` after the `sleep 10000` is responsible for this ? I would be very surprised by that. I think that is a syntax requirement. Without it bash prints `bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`.

Comment: Also @DavidC.Rankin.  Both of the following have the same process tree: `bash -c "sleep 10000; "` and  `bash -c "sleep 10000 "`. With and without the final semicolon. If the semicolon were the reason in the example in my question, would you also not expect a difference in this case ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any affect from an ending `';'`. I suspect, but have not looked at the code, that when a final `';'` is reached, all that occurs is a check to see if anything else follows, and if not, it is silently discarded.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have updated my question with a duplicate question from Unix&Linux. It looks like the bash code as one of the piped commands causes a subshell to be spawned.